# Xemacs perl compilation can't go to error position, by showing "Wrong type argument" error

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

After compilation of perl script I get syntax error in compilation window. If I try to use `Goto Error` Command, it not working and show error message:

```
Wrong type argument: listp, "^\\s-*\\(at \\(.*\\):\\([0-9]+\\)\)"
```

I use `cperl 6.2` and `xemacs 21.5.34`.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I *strongly* recommend moving from XEmacs to GNU Emacs. XEmacs is largely abandoned. Its website hasn't been updated in two years, and the most recent commit to its "bleeding edge" Mercurial repository, listed as official on its website, is a year and a half older than that. In the meantime, GNU Emacs has surpassed XEmacs in virtually every way. It's hard to overstate the improvements we've seen in the last few releases. The GNU Emacs community is dramatically larger as well, so you're much more likely to get useful help.

Comment: Ok. I change to GNU Emacs. How can I enable perl syntax check? I run cperl but syntax check is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

> I change to GNU Emacs. How can I enable perl syntax check? I run cperl but syntax check is disabled?

CPerl's "Check syntax" menu item relies on something called [`mode-compile`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeCompile). If you don't have that installed it won't work. I've never used `mode-compile`, and can't offer much help there.

If you're going to be installing another package for syntax checking anyway, and assuming you're using GNU Emacs 24 or later, I suggest using the excellent [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) instead. Flycheck [supports syntax checking for Perl](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/languages.html#perl) as well as a huge number of other languages. In addition to regular syntax checking using the `perl` binary, Flycheck also supports syntax checking using `Perl::Critic`.

Flycheck is available via [MELPA](http://melpa.org/) and [MELPA stable](http://stable.melpa.org/). Once it is installed, add

```
(global-flycheck-mode)
```

to your configuration to enable Flycheck globally. If you've got `perl` on your path you should start getting syntax checking.